# How to make content from an input box transfer to an paragraph element, like a blog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogs

I am trying to make a website thats like a blog but i cant figure out how to align text in an input element and make the entry from that element be posted and saved as a paragraph element below it.... like facebook. I know this isn't a very detailed question but im new to HTML, Javascript and CSS.

Fiddle with it here.

```
<head>

    <title font-weight="bold">Social Rejects</title>
    <link href="font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href='font.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="sr-head-ico.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--- PASSWORD PROTECTION SCRIPT

        function TheLogin() {

        var password = '69';

        if (this.document.loginsec.sec.value == password) {
            top.location.href="secret.html";
        }
        else {
        location.href="incorrect.html";
        }
        }

    // End hiding --->
    </script>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="pheader">
        <img src="sr-head.png"></img>
        <right>
        <a href="login.html">Log-In</a>
        </right>
    </div>
        <!-- Main body -->

<div class="jumbotron">


<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

<div class="nav"
    <ul>
        <li href="index.html">Home</li>
        <li href="#">My Page</li>
        <li href="#">My Followers</li>
        <li href="#">Following</li>
        <li href="#">About S.R.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="na">
    <div class="nti">Feature not yet added!
    </div>
    <info>This feature has not yet been constructed. Please check back for more info.<br>
    <a style="text-decoration: underline;">These things will be broken for <b>awhile</b>.</a></info><br><br><center>
    <confirm>Okay</confirm>
    </center>
</div>
<div class="secret">
    <div class="nti">Congratulations!
    </div>
    <center>
    Enter Secret password:<br>
        <form name="loginsec" style="margin: 0px">
        <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="sec" size="24" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;" style="width: 252px; height: 26px; margin: 5px;"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Click to check" style="width : 150px; margin: 3px; border: 0px; padding: 10px;" onClick="TheLogin(this.form)">
        </form>
    </center><center>
    <confirm>Okay</confirm>
    </center>
</div>
<div class=main-body>
    <ti>Rodney Mahan</ti><br>
    <beta>This page is in beta</beta>

    <div class="profile">
        <div class="header"
        <ul>
            <li><b>About Rodney:</b></li>
            <li>Enjoys <b>Making Websites</b></li>
            <li><b>CEO</b> of <b>Mahan's Web Design</b></li>
            <li>Born on <b>February 4th, 1999</b></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog">
        <blog-title>Rodney's Blog</blog-title><br>
        <form>
        <input placeholder="New Post"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MahanWebDesign/bm8fz2u5/1/

Comment: I'm thinking it's a lot more complicated than you think, you'll need a database to store the blog posts etc.

Answer (score 0):

First off, good on you for tackling something like this.  Adeneo is right that it may be more complicated than you think.  It may help to think of this in 3 levels:

1. Front-end: This is your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
2. Middle-layer: This is your communication between the front-end and the database.
3. Back-end: Database where your store things like posts, users & accounts, etc.

Usually your JavaScript will talk to the middle layer through an API (Application Programmer Interface) like REST to actually send and retrieve the data.  You're right that this question is too general.  If you're doing this as an exercise to learn that's one thing, and if you're just trying to get something up and running that's another.

If you're just trying to get something up and running, try looking at [WordPress.com](https://wordpress.com/).  It'll host it for you as well, and there's no messing about with servers.

If you're looking to learn about HTML, CSS, and JavaScript you might try [Wordpress.org](http://www.wordpress.org). Once you get it installed on a server it takes care of layers 2 and 3 for you, and it gives you a lot of help with layer 1.  You can download it and then start looking to see how it does what it does.  That will involve some PHP as well as HTML and CSS.

If you're looking to learn about databases and how they work, you might start with a simple one like Firebase.  You can get a free developer license and start experimenting with JSON and other ways to send and store information. MySQL is a good place to start if you really want to get into database structure and interaction.

You don't have to learn it all at once, of course, and a lot of people specialize in just one or two layers.

Comment: Thank you very much I am a rookie, but I want to make this completely on my own. could you please help me in a collab... that would be great.
http://jsfiddle.net/MahanWebDesign/bm8fz2u5/1/#&togetherjs=ad21QeUysC

Comment: I wish I had more time to help you with a collab.  I guess my question is what do you mean by "this" when you say you want to make this completely on your own.  I work mainly in layer 1 above, and a wee bit in layer 2.  I'm not your person for setting up databases, but that's really where you need to start if you want to be able to save anything.  I get that you want to learn all of them, but you have to pick one of them to start with first - break the problem down into digestible chunks.

Comment: Okay honestly, Im attempting to make my own social media website. Im sure your probably thinking "yeah right this little kid can make  a social website... psh.." Actually, everything that I've written in the fiddle i made from complete scratch. i just need a bit of help. Im working with MySQL right now. Learning a little at a time.